# Wrong data will appear when double click

Tags: excel, vba

Why when I double click at list box, the data will come out the previous one? And sometimes, it just comes out the random data from the list box.

FYI, it will happen on "Amount to be Collected (Emp 4)", "Acct. Mgr(Emp 5)", "Phone (Emp 6)" and "Email (Emp 7)".

Here is the image so that you can see clearer.

[image]

```
Private Sub lstEmployee_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
'dim the variables
Dim i As Integer
On Error Resume Next

'find the selected list item
i = Me.lstEmployee.ListIndex

Dim methodsOfCommunication() As String

Me.Emp1.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(0, i)
Select Case Me.lstEmployee.Column(2, i)
    Case "Yes"
        Me.Emp2.Value = True
        Me.Emp3.Value = False
    Case "No"
        Me.Emp2.Value = False
        Me.Emp3.Value = True
End Select

' Reset Methods of Communication checkboxes.
Me.Emp8.Value = False
Me.Emp9.Value = False
Me.Emp10.Value = False
Me.Emp11.Value = False
Me.Emp12.Value = False
' Set Methods of Communication checkboxes.
methodsOfCommunication = Split(Me.lstEmployee.Column(1, i), ", ")
For i = LBound(methodsOfCommunication, 1) To UBound(methodsOfCommunication, 1)
    Select Case methodsOfCommunication(i)
        Case "Whatsapp"
            Me.Emp8.Value = True
        Case "Phone Call"
            Me.Emp9.Value = True
        Case "Facebook"
            Me.Emp10.Value = True
        Case "Email"
            Me.Emp11.Value = True
        Case "SMS"
            Me.Emp12.Value = True
    End Select
Next

Me.Emp4.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(3, i)
Me.Emp5.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(4, i)
Me.Emp6.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(5, i)
Me.Emp7.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(6, i)
Me.Emp13.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(7, i)
Me.Emp14.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(8, i)
Me.Emp15.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(9, i)

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: As a note, I hope those are fake phone numbers/emails - otherwise you should really redact anything like that when posting here.

Comment: It actually just a random number. Don't worry :)

Comment: Is your list indexing off by 1? Are you also sure you're not tripping an error, preventing the rest of your boxes from populating?

Comment: @dwirony on my behalf, I am not sure where is the error. I try to google to find the solution, but I did not find it. :(

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: Also step through your code line-by-line (debugging) and compare expected vs actual behavoir.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon done, but still the same.

Comment: If you move the following lines: `Me.Emp6.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(5, i)` and `Me.Emp7.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(6, i)` above the remaining lines starting with `Me.Emp4.Value = Me.lstEmployee.Column(3, i)`..., do the Phone and Email TextBoxes populate as expected?

Comment: Why are you responding to `lstEmployee_DblClick` instead of `lstEmployee_Change`? The code makes it look like that's the event you want, and a double-click is typically not associated with "select". It also means that users *have to* interact with it using the mouse, and any experienced data entry person will tell you that's not the tool of choice for rapidly entering data...

Comment: @KenLove Exactly!!! I do the same thing just now, and finally!!!!! T.T Thank you so much ken!!

Comment: @KenLove/OP the mere fact that this changes anything whatsoever is a massive tell-tale that the entire code needs a serious and thorough redesign.

Comment: The error occurs when the ComboBoxes are being set. That's why moving the code for the TextBoxes above the code for the ComboBoxes made it so that the TextBoxes could at least be set properly. ComboBoxes usually require more logic to set depending on their settings. What are the ComboBox properties for the following: BoundColumn, ColumnCount, ControlSource, MatchRequired, and RowSource.